# Loop through subset of parameters while renendering part of YAML in Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure-pipelines

Is there a way (other that the ones specified at the bottom of the question) to loop through just a subset of parameters while conditionally renendering parts of YAML in Azure Pipelines. I'm trying to do something like this:

```yaml
parameters:
- name: firstParam
  default: string1
- name: secondParam
  default: string2
.
.
.
- name: xParam

jobs:
- ${{ each currParam in [parameters.firstParam, parameters.secondParam] }}
  - job: Job1
...
```

Note that, `[parameters.firstParam, parameters.secondParam]` is invalid syntax.

Is there a way to do that other than changing those parameters into a single array like this:

```yaml
parameters:
- name: params
  type: object
  default: 
  - string1
  - string2
.
.
.
- name: xParam

jobs:
- ${{ each currParam in parameters.params }}
  - job: Job1
...
```

or looping through all parameters and making obscure chunk of code:

```yaml
parameters:
- name: firstParam
  default: string1
- name: secondParam
  default: string2
.
.
.
- name: xParam

jobs:
  - ${{ each parameter in parameters }}:
    - ${{ if or(eq(parameter.key, 'firstParam'), eq(parameter.key, 'secondParam')) }}:
```

Comment: I doubt you’ll find much better than the second example—why don’t you want to use it?